# Prove using mean value theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

$|\arctan(\frac{a}{4})^{4}-\arctan(\frac{b}{4})^{4}|\leq \pi^{3}\cdot|a-b|$

I started with $f(x)=\arctan(\frac{x}{4})^{4}$.

The function is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable in (a,b)

So there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that  $f'(c)=\frac{\arctan(\frac{b}{4})^{4}-\arctan(\frac{a}{4})^{4}}{b-a}$. From this I have

$$|\frac{-1}{1+c^{2}}|= \frac{1}{1+c^{2}}=\frac{|\arctan(\frac{b}{4})^{4}-\arctan(\frac{a}{4})^{4}|}{|b-a|}$$

and $a<c<b$. How to get the inequality with $\frac{1}{1+c^{2}}$from it?

Comment: You are missing the outer derivative or at least parts of it in the derivative of $f$.

Comment: What is the Lagrange method?

Comment: You could use `\text{arccot}(x)` to get $\text{arccot}(x)$ as originally intended. Because the range of the arcus cotangent is $(0,\pi)$, you also get the indicated upper bound and not $(\pi/2)^3$ as with the arcus tangent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derivative of $f$ is

$$f'(x)=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac x4\right)^3}{1+\left(\frac x4\right)^2}$$
so we get using that $\vert \arctan(y)\vert\le \pi$

$$\vert f'(x)\vert\le \pi^3 \quad\forall x\in\Bbb R $$
and then you can conclude the desired inequality.

Comment: $|\arctan y|\le\frac\pi2$, but originally the question was about the arcus cotangent and there the upper bound $\pi$ would apply.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x) = x^4$, and suppose $|x| \le M$, then $|f'(x)| \le 4 M^3$ for $|x| \le M$.

Using the mean value theorem
we have $|f(x)-f(y)| \le 4 M^3 |x-y|$.

Let $M = {\pi \over 2}$ and note that $|\arctan x| \le M$ and
$|\arctan' x| \le 1$, hence
$|(\arctan x)^4 - (\arctan y)^4| \le {1 \over 2} \pi^3 |\arctan x -\arctan y | \le {1 \over 2} \pi^3 |x-y|$.

Now let $x = {a \over 4}, y = {b \over 4}$ to get.
$|(\arctan {a\over 4})^4 - (\arctan {b \over 4})^4|  \le {1 \over 2} \pi^3 |{a \over 4} -{b \over 4}| \le { \pi^3 \over 8} |x-y| $.

Comment: @LutzL: Thanks for checking, I think I goofed.

Comment: @LutzL: Fixed! Thanks again.